# clasp: Nested trigger doesn't fire on V8 engine

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

### Problem

Nested trigger on GAS v8 engine doesn't work if I use clasp typescript project. "Nested trigger" means
 a scheduled function which is programmatically created by another scheduled function.

- clasp: v2.3.0

### How to reproduce

1. Create clasp project
   `clasp create --type standalone`
2. Create a TypeScript file called `main.ts` with the following contents:

```js
// Set trigger on a specific time.
function setTrigger(time:Date, func:string): void {
  console.log('This is scheduling: ' + func + ' on ' + time);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(func)
      .timeBased()
      .at(time)
      .create();
}
// Set trigger on 5 minutes after.
function schedule() {
  const toBeScheduled = new Date();
  toBeScheduled.setMinutes(toBeScheduled.getMinutes() + 5);
  setTrigger(toBeScheduled, "doSomething");
}

// function which will fire.
function doSomething() {
  console.log("DO SOMETHING");
}
```

3. Create a json file called `tsconfig.json` with the following contents:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "target": "ES2019",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

4. push code
   `clasp push`
5. Set trigger for `schedule()` function every 5 minutes so that the `doSomething()` fire every 5 min.

but actually the **`doSomething()` doesn't fire. The trigger is set but it will be disabled with UNKNOWN cause.**

### Note

1. If I manually execute `schedule()`, then `doSomething()` fires as expected.
2. If I create a GAS project with exactly same contents **without clasp**, then `doSomething()` fires as expected.
3. If I push code without v8 engine as following, then everything works fine.

   - Remove `"runtimeVersion": "V8"` from `appsscript.json`
   - Remove `tsconfig.json` file from project.

Is there something I'm missing?

#### Update(2020/04/18)

I have created issue on the issue tracker.
https://issuetracker.google.com/154366756

Comment: Have you made sure you're not hitting quotas? If so, create a issue in issue tracker

Comment: OK. I'll check existing issues and open an issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi ! Were you hitting any [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)? Also, if you have openned an issue, could you please share it in your question so that everyone with the same issue can go and check its progress? Thanks!

Comment: No, I’m not hitting any quotas/limitations. Sure I will share the issue when I open. Thank you for your comment!